# Тайга — откуда такое слово?

Tags: этимология

Интересует этимология слова "тайга". Кто как думает?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**ТАЙГА** «полоса диких труднопроходимых хвойных лесов умеренного пояса». В рус. словарях отмечается с середины XIX в. В литерат. яз. проникло из сибирских диал. Общепринятой этимол. не имеет. Одни полагают, что слово **тайга** происходит из алтайских языков. Ему родственны тюрк, taiγa «крутая горная скала»; тур. daγ «гора». Ср. татарск. Аюдаг 
«Медведь-гора». В соответствии с этой гипотезой у слова тайга знач. «лес» является вторичн. Ср. в «Опыте областного великорусского словаря» 1852 г. *тайга* «дикие лесистые пространства в горах». Другие считают слово *тайга* заимствованием из якутского яз., в котором тайга значит «непроходимый лес». (Этимологический словарь Цыганенко)
Есть ещё версия: от древнего "тай" - конец. Тогда "тайга" - конец чего-то (вот только не ясно - чего).

Comment: Это значит я попутал? Всегда считал финоугорским словом. 
ну лда ладно, а чем Вики-то врет, кто-нить понял?

Comment: @behemothus, Вы два раза написали "финно-угорский" с одним "н". Это опечатка или Вы действительно так пишите? (зная Вашу, как бы это сказать помягче, быстроту письма, не удивлюсь, если опечатка).  

Впрочем, посмотрела в Гугле. Поисковик исправил на два "н", но есть и Ваше написание.

Comment: Да, есть сведения об истории термина, но об этимологиии слова - ни слова :-))).

Comment: @DocentI, да, спасибо. Разумеется это ошибка. Но в данном случае это не просто описка, такое написание можно встретить в текстах определенного времени, по памяти - годов шестидесятых. Написание одно время было неустоявшимся, предлагалось писать именно так, слитно и с одним Н. Вроде как от "финских угров". 

Вообще с этим терсином большая непонятка. Был термин "угро(-)финский", он, естественно, двух Н не требовал. По чьей-то прихоти его переделали, поменяв местами основы - и про второе Н забыли.  

Аналогичная история, кстати, проискходила с "винно-водочным".

Comment: Возможно я попутал с "тундрой". Ну да не суть важно. 
Интереснее другое, откуда в финский пришло члово taiha?

Comment: Ну касательно сентенции: 

> википедия врет

это провокация, а то ведь все привыкли чуть что лезть в Яндекс и Википедию, чтобы заставить головой подумать - я и написал такую провокацию.

Теперь по-поводу происхождения: я таки сторонник "якутской" версии - тайга слово имевшее (и до сих пор имеющее) смысл "непроходимый лес" - см. якутско-русский словарь Пекарского.

Answer (score 2):

Слово финно-угорское. Скорее всего, пришло в русский от коренных обитателей Пермского края.
Не знаю, что вы имели в виду под "Википедия врет". Во-первых, голословные обвинения не приветсвуются, во-вторых, Вики ничего не говорит про происхожение самого слова.
Зато в любом этимологическом словаре можно найти нужную "инфу".

Answer (score 2):

Предполагаю, что русское слово "тайга" происходит от якутского слова "тыа" (лес). "Тыа5а" - "в лесу" - по-русски будет произноситься как "тайга".

Answer (score -1):

Слово ***"тайга"*** - это русское произношение якутского слова ***"тыаhа"***, которое означает ***"лесное"***, ***"в лесу"***.

Answer (score -2):

Тайна, есть такое слово в русском языке.  От того и тайга.

Насчет га --

Вага
Вага
вага ва́га 1. "вес, тяжесть", 2. "весы", 3. "перекладина на тележном дышле", 4. "рычаг". Также диал. ваг "приспособление для поднятия повозки при смазке колес", севск. Переносное знач. "уважение, ценность" из знач. "вес". Ср. укр. ва́га, блр. ва́га "весы, тяжесть; уважение", словен. vâga, польск. waga "вес", чеш. váha, слвц. váha, в.-луж. waha, н.-луж. waga. Заимств. из д.-в.-н. wâga, нов.-в.-н. Wage "весы", которое пришло к вост. славянам, наверное, через польск. (Mi. EW 374; Уленбек, AfslPh 15, 492; Кипарский 267 и сл.). От ва́га произведены ва́жный, диал. ва́жить "взвешивать". Некоторые знач. трудно объяснить, принимая во внимание производный характер слова; ср. отва́га (см. ниже). Голуб (321) видит здесь исконнослав. корень, который он относит к везу́, везти́, что сомнительно в фонетическом отношении. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

---

В чем неправ Фасмер, слишком мелко копал, да ему это и не надо было. Абы как, лишь бы утвердить в русском немецкое либо тюркское происхождение.  Наци, одним словом. А мы тут Унтерменши.
Вага-прежде всего-это связь с корнем га, который в России уж слишком часто попадается в гидронимах(названиях рек и озер) и в топонимах. И не только в России. Есть топонимы такие и в Италии, к примеру.

Скорее всего само слово обязано своему происхождению характерному крику гусей, точнее косяков гусей, летящих клином,  ГА.
Один из видов гусей так и называется-Гага, гагара,  где второй корень обозначат небосвод/солнце. И направление пути перелета—на юг, к солнцу.
В голландском идти---gaat.
В английском идти—go, в датском –gå, go.
Связь этих слов по смыслу и произношению очевидна и обжалованию не полежит.
Связь состоит в том, что пути-дороги в древности были водными. Это и отражает этот корень.  ГА  прежде всего направление и дорога. , а уж потом просто путь по воде. Топоним.
В латыни это отражено в слове идти—vade, водой.
Вага, помимо перечисленных значений, исконно просто палка, предназначенная для хождения по топким, болотистым местам. Своего рода щуп для проверки: можно туда ступать или нет. A корень ва, скорее всего, от вода. А торговых путей задешево посуху не было. Дорога—дорогое удовольствие, путь надо прорубать в лесах и переправы делать. Мостить. Гатить. Синоним ваги—слега. Еще одно слово для обозначения палки при хождении исключительно по моховым болотам. Мхам. Только на них образуется след. Есть и еще одна палка,  лага, как лежащая на земле или связывающе бревно, опора.
Еще одна палка  батога---от нее батоги, батогами наказание.   http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C1%E0%F2%EE%E3
 И близко—ватага, бандиты-разбойники. У Фасмера уж слишком прямолинейно. Сначала первый корень надо вычислить , а вата—и ва от того, что именно на водной дороге грабили,  то есть объединение в шайку вторично. А дорога первично.
Ватага
ватага вата́га "гурьба, стая; шайка", укр. вата́га – то же, др.-русск. ватага "шатер", грам. 1234 – 1304 гг.; Ипатьевск. летоп. под 1184 и 1190 гг.; см. Корш, AfslPh 9, 659. Заимствиз др.-чув. *våtaɣ,* uotaɣ, др.-тюрк. otaɣ "палатка, комната, семья", тур. odak, oda "комната, дом"; ср. калм. otɔg "род, община, отделение" (Рамстедт, KWb. 291). Ср. окончание лачу́га, яру́га; см. Мелиоранский, ИОРЯС 10, 4, 118 и сл.; Корш, AfslPh 9, 659; Младенов 58. Менее удачно толкование из сев.-тюрк. vataga "множество, артель рыбаков" (Mi. EW 376; TEl., Доп. 1, 65; Горяев, ЭС 40; Вайганд, JIRSpr. 16, 230; Тиктин 3, 1718), которое, скорее, само заимств. из русск. Неубедительно также объяснение из рум. vătas̨ "сторож", которое производят через тур. vattas "пастух" из араб. vaṭṭâs – то же; ср. Крелиц (60) против Корша (ИОРЯС 8, 4, 58; AfslPh 9, 678), Миклошича (Mi. TEI. 2, 185, Доп. 1, 65). Против этой этимологии см. Мелиоранский, там же; Локоч 168. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

Дорога не от того что просто путь в смысле колеи запыленной, а в смысле того, что дорого.

Дорога
дорога I доро́га I., укр. доро́га, блр. даро́га, сербск.-цслав. драга "долина", сербохорв. дра̏га, словен. drága "овраг, лощина", др.-чеш. dráha "дорога", польск. droga "дорога", в.-луж. dróha "след, дорога, улица", н.-луж. droga "улица". Из и.-е. *dorgh-; связано с дёргать (Бернекер 1, 212; Мейе, Et. 253; Торбьёрнссон 2, 21; Погодин, РФВ 35, 143; Брюкнер 97, КZ 48, 216) и означает "продранное в лесу пространство"; см. Забелин у Горяева, ЭС 95. Ср. также русск.-цслав. подрагъ "край". Менее вероятно родство со шв. dråg "длинная, узкая впадина в почве, низина, долина", др.-исл. draga "тянуть" (Перссон 492; Траутман, BSW 45; Торп 210 и сл). •• [См. еще Мошинский, Zasiąg, стр. 159. - Т.] II II. "татаро-монг. чиновник", в грам. XIII – XIV вв. (Срезн.), также дорага, Котов (около 1625 г.). Из монг. daruga, калм. darɣɔ "старейшина племени или отряда, атаман, начальник округа"; см. даруга. III доро́га доро́жка "снаряд для ловли рыбы, в основном щуки", арханг. (Подв.), олонецк. (Кулик.) Вероятно, заимств. из сканд.: ср. норв.-датск. dorg-тo же, шв. dörj, dorj, др.-исл. dorg - то же, которые связываются с др.-исл. draga "тащить" (Фасмер, RS 5, 122). О герм. словах см. Фальк-Торп 149; Ельквист 1, 171. Из сканд. заимств. также фин. tork(k)o "вид удочки", см. Сетэлэ, FUF 13, 461; из нем. Darge "вид удочки" происходит польск. darka – то же; см. Сляский, PF 8, 34. Русск. слово большей частью отождествляется этимологически с доро́га I; см. Хольтхаузен, Awn. Wb. 38; Торбьёрнссон 2, 21; Маценауэр, LF 7, 46. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

Дорога по жизни происходит от дара, ФАСМЕР ПОПУТАЛ БОЖИЙ ДАР С ЯИЧНИЦЕЙ.
Драго—ценность. Dārga, dārgi  основа в латышском –дорого.
В финском слово дорого созвучно с колеей—kalliisti, а финская дорога—остаток от русского-путь- tie. То же самое в латышском, дорога- kelias.
А в эстонском дорого- üliväga!!!!!! И синоним—kallilt.
Ну, прямо даже не совпадение!!!
Дорога уже потом—это колея, след, ложбина и даже две, если не волоком. И действительно, как толкует  улица, если в селении.
Дорожка-один из самых древних способов ловли рыбы—блеснение. Так, то блесна делает колею в воде. Это не само приспособление, а именно способ, ловить по дороге. Корабль идет и тащит, если клюнет-дергает. Закидывать не надо. Или сам поддергиваешь, чтоб блесна поиграла.
Ох уж этот Фасмер!!! Не рыбак!!! И рыбу даже в этимологии не ловил.  А место рыбное!

А палка, для помощи при ходьбе, есть палка.
 Получается, есть посох, палка в значении для ходьбы посуху, а другая –вага-для ходьбы по топкому. А кто в древней Руси по- сухому ходил? Да не было таких, пока дороги не появились. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85

Значение такой палки-ваги у одного, в руках-оружие.  А от ваги-- вожак, важик, не отважный вовсе, а первопроходец, тот который за собой ведет.  У другого вага– рычаг, способ перемещения и подъема тяжестей,  рычишь, но двигаешь!!!от того и РЫЧАг.
В английском вообще лом—вага—crowbar  дословно- ворон + медведь.
А ворон у русских—одно из значений, рычаг с крюком, военное приспособление,
У русских «медведей», в английском нет этимологии данного слова-bear. Зато в русском этимология прослеживается до исходного возгласа брррр  и ощущений холода и страха, аж до мурашек по спине при встрече с хозяином леса.  От этого названия медведя—бер,  идет и место его зимней спячки, берлога. От него же название топора – бердыш, оружие для охоты на медведя. Дышло-тоже палка. А само название - медведь-синоним, появившийся от наблюдений за его образом жизни и повадками. Ведает  мед? Да нет, ни в коем случае. Чисто цветовые ассоциации с цветом  меда, а уж потом с медом.
А вот украинское  вeдмiдь,  не перевертыш, а исторически сложившееся наименование тех людей, которые знают, где не мед искать, а медь, ну очень похожую по цвету на мед.

У торговца вага - перекладина для весов. 
А отважить—побить вагой, отходить палкой.
Тогда важный—это вооруженный как минимум такой палкой.
А отважный—способный применить это оружие, когда надо.
От корня га-слово гать,  дорога через топкое место, болото, мощеная палками. Глагол-гатить.
Слово Ваган
Ваган
ваган вага́н "корыто, деревянная миска", укр. вага́н, болг. вага́н "определенная мера", сербохорв. ва̀ган "мера зерна", словен. vagàn, vagána – то же, чеш. vahan, слвц. vahan "квашня". Из слав. заимств. лит. vogõnas "круглая деревянная посудина для сливочного масла", лтш. *vāgans, откуда vānags "широкое, плоское блюдо", др.-прусск. wogonis "вид блюда", далее, эст. vaagen, род. п. vaagna "миска", морд. э. vaḱan – то же; см. М. – Э. 4, 498; Траутман, Apr. Sprd. 465; Миккола, ÄВ 53; Брюкнер, AfslPh 6, 606; 20, 498; Скарджюс 239. Неубедительно объяснение Лескина (Bildung 524 и сл.) лтш. слова из эст. (см. М. – Э. (там же); Буга, KS 1, 301; Тойвонен, FUF 17, 285), который, однако, принимает для морд. слова kk. Последнее родственно фин. vakka; см. Паасонен, Mordv. Chrest. 149. Согласно Г. Майеру (Ngr. Stud. 2, 15), нов.-греч. βαγένι "бочка" тоже заимств. из слав. (-ενι по аналогии λαγένι), тогда как Маценауэр (86), Фасмер (Гр.-сл. эт. З, 41) предполагали, вряд ли верно, обратное направление заимствования. Трудно определить источник этой широко распространенной группы слов. Если учитывать географию, то предположение о финно-уг. происхождении сомнительно. То же следует сказать относительно прежней гипотезы Фасмера (там же) о ср.-греч.* βαγάνι(ον), которое якобы в свою очередь заимств. из народнолат. cavaneus : cavus "полый", ит. gavagno "корзина"; не принимая во внимание гипотезу о новогреч. посредничестве, так думает еще теперь Младенов (95). Неудовлетворительно также ввиду широкого распространения слав. *vaganъ объяснение Штрекеля (69 и сл.) всех этих слов из фриульск. vagàn, bagàn "бочонок с вином", которое связано с bàge "мех, бурдюк" от bac-; ср. лат. baccinum "таз, лохань" (иначе М.-Любке 70). Тогда следовало бы ожидать только слав.* bočьnъ. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

скорее всего, пошло от слова вага, в значении весов у торговцев, как мера чего-либо, того, что к ваге подвешивают, емкость, мерка, а уж потом посуда.

Есть в  русском некоторое соответствие букв   Ж  и  Г. Это как раз и проявляется в словах родственных по смыслу.
важный-отвага
берег-побережье
друг-друже-дружба
и т.д.
Cвязана такая замена с  тем, что в древности путали запись и произношение  букв.
Звук   Ж  записывали по разному:  «латиницей»---g, j, кириллицей, а потом в зависимости от того или иного грамотея  читали как Г, а другие с точностью до наоборот, как Ж или «ие»-(й).
Таких  разночтений масса. И не только этих букв.
Это сказалось во всех европейских языках,  у нас region  толкуют как район и как регион.
А само слово появилось от исходного РЕЖЬ.
К примеру,  латинское h  и в до-петровские времена читали по-русски как Г, сегодня в украинском hotel—готель, в русском Holland-Голландия. И наоборот русская рукописная-малая д в европейских языках с легкой руки толмача-переписчика, превращалась в g и читалось как Ж или Г.
А кто записывал? По-видимому, в большинстве своем это были монахи, несшие во вполне грамотную страну тот самый, синтезированный Кириллом и Мефодием новый алфавит, и сами не понимающие разницы в транскрипции и транслитерации, а затем переносившие искажения обратно. Тот же Фасмер в современное время использует эти совпадения—переходы букв от языка к языку при написании чужых слов.
Вот эти переходы туда и обратно:
G g  латынь, как Ж, Г
Д д  русский, как g G в латыни
 J j латынь,  как  Ж  или  Й 
H h латынь,  как  Г или Х
С латынь, как Ц или К     ( ceasar      кесарь)  а слово царь и так уже имеется.
С русское, как К С латынь.
Х русское, как Сh  латынь. К   кси
C русское в S латынь и наоборот уже З.
Б----В----W V B
В латыни    V-f-B
Пойди потом догадайся, если языком в полной мере не владеешь, а так по верхам, о смысловом истинном значении той или иной записи при переводе.

Отличный пример:  немцы слово народ толкуют  как Фолькс---volks,  однако в нашей транскрипции это волки. А мы то сами в их речи—имеем кличку—медведи.
В баскском  идти—joatea,  про идти в разных языках уже упоминалось.
У нас от га  идет трогать в смысле трогай с места. В свою очередь  тро  связано с быстро. А глаголы трогать, тонуть  -в смысле прикосновения, связана с упомянутым трогай  чисто в плане действия, понукания.

Поэтому гидронимы нынче есть как на Га, так и на Жа.
Список гидронимов на Га, далеко не полный.
Бурга
Ваенга 
Вага
Варзуга
Ваймуга
Вига
Вилга
Волга
Волманга
Ветлуга
Визинга
Вожега 
Иоканьга
Индига
Инга
Кистега
Кичменьга
Кокшеньга
Кокшага
Кондега 
Куга

Ладога    вполне возможно—ладный путь. 
Лига
Лапшанга
Лоптюга
Луга   ----лужа. Что река мелкая, так про то только местные знают. Пойма широкая и топкая. И впадает в лужу-Финский залив.  Залив и есть лужа. Заливает –от того и луг с заменой буквы.
Луданга
Луженьга
Мга
Мига
Мшага
Мегрега
Молога
Музга
Наньга
Нашига
Нюньга
Онега
Осуга
Патерга
Перенга
Печуга
Пинега
Свияга
Синьга
Сога
Соньга
Сутяга
Тюньга
Унга
Урга
Урынга
Уфтюга
Шаранга
Шарженга
Юга
Юнга
Юронга
Яренга

И там, где есть такие гидронимы, нередко встречаются гидронимы на Жа:

Веряжа
Дёржа
Кавожа
Кобожа
Ковжа 
Кожа
Ичежа
Лежа
Лжа
Межа
Мжа
Пимжа
Псижа
Пчевжа
Раужа
Ружа
Рюмжа 
Сарагожа
Сегжа
Сегежа 
Снежа
Согожа
Сунжа
Съежа 
Унжа
Унжа
Усожа
Тиржа

А если учесть огрехи в произношении у разных местных говоров,
То Га и Жа нередко со временем превращались  в Ща, Ша, Ча и даже Са и Ца. А с учетом  j –окончание превращается в Йа, ея  и как пример множество рек с  такими окончаниями. 
То есть окончания эти несут один смысл. И гидронимов подобных, подавляющее большинство среди старинных названий. А начальные корни гидронимов ---это те самые забытые как по смыслу, так и по звучанию древние слова или их остатки, расшифровка значений которых первостепенная задача для топонимики. Не все конечно, но большая часть, определенно.

Пример из польского, украинского, белорусского  слово  внимание—uwaga,  почему, да потому, что возникло из междометия  у! вага!  Палка ушла, провалилась.  Внимание—опасность!
Drogo droga  соответственно дорого и дорога.
В обособленном мальтийском  дорога—treq,   а дальше известное трек—и как созвучен в этом языке синоним слова :  дорога- toroq 
Вот и присмотришься к нашему родному  ТОРГ---а от дороги и идет! И тюркское—торок-к седлу мешок, оттуда и глагол приторочить.
Да и сами названия: тюрки с торками и турками---все оттуда. То есть родной русский, после обработки торговым людом. Купцами.
И тогда понятны многие топонимы  Турку, Торжок, Торгау.

В шведском тоже комбинация междометия с отметкой голосом буквально—upp-märk-samhet уже в принципе дословный перевод.
 На том же шведском  дорога- väg,  маршрут- vägen, а в немецком – Weg.

Так что пути дороги неисповедимы для тех, кто сравнивает абы как.   tra

А поскольку дорога—дорогого стоит, потрудиться надо немало, в Европе, в частности в итальянском, появилось слово –Stradale, в других языках strada.

Но в русском то—тяжело только на словах, урожай собирать,  СТРАДА. А на деле радость и делать это надо быстро, урожай собирать. Но монахи в церковнославянском превратили это в горе.
Вот и дороги—строят, страдают, получается возврат---автострада.
А от дороги и дорого---появились и другие слова.

Дряга
дряга дряга́ "судорога", дряга́ть "дергаться, судорожно бить(ся)", дрягва́ "вид студня", словен. drégati, drȇgam "топать, толкать". Праслав. *dręg-; ср. дёргать (Бернекер 1, 222). Ср. сл. •• [Сюда же передря́ги мн. – Т.] Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

передряга-место на дороге, где потряхивает. Неровный путь, в том числе и жизненный. А дряга – дрожать.
Само слово су-дорога, ноги сводит от пути длинного, дороги. Сегодня сокращение в разговорном судорга. Вот потихоньку да потихоньку корешки и отыскиваются. Не просто судорога, а судороги,  их много, и следуют друг за дружкой.  Об этом и говорит первый корень—нынче его считают приставкой—СУ, немного измененное со временем написание корня СО.  А он используется в словах: содружество, соединение, супружество, супруг, (с-упруг-га)-сопротивление, и т.д. Значение—объединение. А объединить—все равно, что сложить, получается МНОГО. То есть много дороги—имеем судороги.
И смотрим, что там у Фасмера насчет судороги.

Судорога
судорога су́дорога диал. су́дорга – то же (Преобр.), укр. су́дорга. От су- и дёргать. Ср. лит. sudìrgti "разозлиться" (Мi. ЕW 42; Брюкнер, KZ 48, 216; Педерсен, Kelt. Gr. I, 105; Преобр. I, 179; II, 413). Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

да просто отписка у Фасмера. И сравнивать не с чем. Разве что с выражением «все, держите меня» можно сравнить латышское «дергаться».
У нас же есть слово синоним,  трясти –дрожь.
Этимология слов дрожь, дрожки от дороги.  А вот слова держать, держава  имеют более сложное  происхождение. Слово дорого тоже.
Рожь  режь  жать  гать дорога дорого продать. Продажа. Дюже дорого дюжину продать. Игра слов,  но как зависит от этой экономической игры дружба.
Ничего нет дороже дружбы, сотрудничества во всем. В том числе и в пути-дороге, по-дороге, дороженьке. Дружно.
Друг
Друг
друг I I., см. друк. II II., род. п. друга, мн. друзья́ (из др.-русск. собир. дружья ж., наряду с им. мн. друзи – Соболевский, РФВ 22, 303), укр. друг, ст.-слав. дроугъ φίλος (Клоц., Супр.), болг. друг, сербохорв. дру̑г, словен. drȗg, чеш., слвц. druh, др.-польск. drug. Родственно лит. draũgas "спутник, товарищ", лтш. dràugs, др.-прусск. draugiwaldūnen вин. п. "сонаследник", др.-исл. draugr (поэт.) "муж" (Хольтхаузен, Awn. Wb. 39), гот. driugan στρατεύειν, англос. dréogan "совершать, добиваться", гот. gadraúhts στρατιώτης, д.-в.-н. trucht "отряд воинов, свита", д.-в.-н. truhtîn "военачальник, князь", лит. sudrugti "присоединиться"; см. Бернекер 1, 230 и сл.; Траутман, Apr. Sprd. 322 и сл.; BSW 59; Торп 214; М. – Э. 3, 492; Френкель, BSpr. 109. Сюда не относятся непосредственно (вопреки Преобр. 1, 198) лат. drungus "отряд", ср.-греч. δροῦγγος "отряд" из др.-ирл. drong "толпа, отряд"; см. Вальде – Гофм. 1, 374 и сл. •• [См. еще Трубачев, Терм. родства, стр. 172. – Т.] Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

так что-дорогой друг—практически тавтология. Дешевый друг—дешевка. За душу дешево не берут.
Другой
Другой
другой друго́й друг дру́га, укр. дру́гий "второй", блр. другí – то же, ст.-слав. дроугъ дроуга ἀλλήλους (Мейе 1, 64), дроугъ ἄλλος (Супр.), болг. дру́ги, сербохорв. дру̏гӣ, словен. drȗg "другой", drúgi "второй", чеш. druhý "второй", druh druha "друг друга", польск. drugi "второй", в.-луж. druhi – то же. Первонач. тождественно друг II (Бернекер, 230; Траутман, BSW 59). Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

ой, и не друг вовсе.  «Если друг оказался вдруг» -неожиданно так.
Вы-друг? - Недруг, и дорога у меня другая. Вдвугорядь.

Дружина
Дружина
дружина дружи́на ст.-слав. дроужина συνοδία, συστρατιῶται, ἑταῖροι (Супр.), болг. дружи́на, сербохорв. дру̀жина, словен. družína, чеш. družina, польск. drużyna "отряд, общество". Производное от друг. Напротив, имя собств. ж. р. Дружневна – супруга Бовы (Повесть о Бове-королевиче) не имеет ничего общего с дружи́на и происходит из франко-ит. Drusiana; см. ZfromPh 36, 30 и сл. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973 
ну, тогда и фамилия Брежнев ничего общего с берегом. Все бы ничего , если б не это самое –rusiana. И это—друзья.
Друк  - помощник
Друк
друк род. п. дру́ка, также дрюк "рычаг, шест, жердь", укр. друк, род. п. друка́ - то же, ст.-слав. дрѫгъ ξύλον (Euch. Sin.), болг. дръг "шест", сербохорв. (стар.) друг – то же, словен. drôg "жердь, лестница, стремянка", чеш. drouh "рычаг, плечо рычага, колода", польск. drąg "шест, жердь, рычаг", а также drączek, слвц. druk "рычаг". Формы на k не представляется возможным отделять от форм на g. И та и другая являются древними. Ср., с одной стороны, водрузи́ть, водружа́ть, с другой стороны, дручи́ть, удручи́ть, польск. dręczyć "мучить". Таким образом, k не является продуктом развития отдельных языков, как утверждает Погодин (Следы 256); см. Бернекер 1, 229. Форма на g родственна лит. жем. dránga "толстая жердь", вост.-лит. drángos мн. "телега без колес", др.-исл. drangr "камень, торчащий из земли", drengr "толстый ствол, палка", норв. dreng "толстая палка, колонна", ирл. dringim, кимр. dringo "поднимаюсь, взбираюсь"; см. Бернекер, там же; Торп 211; Цупица, GG 177; Траутман, BSW 59; Шпехт 139. Форма на -k, вероятно, рано возникла под влиянием слова sǫkъ (см. сук) из другой формы, и едва ли родственна лат. truncus "обрубленный, ствол без сучьев, туловище", кимр. trŵch "искалеченный", лит. trenkiù, treñkti "ударить с шумом" (вопреки Бернекеру 1, 230), которые отличаются начальным согласным. Диал. дрюк "сук, длинная палка", донск. (Миртов и др.), возм., является гиперистической формой вместо друк в говорах с веларизацией мягкого р. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

рычаг-вага –дорога,  дрючок-друк—друг    рычаг  и вернулись к началу, к палке-помощнице. К по-дорожнику, другу. Слега, лекарь, лекарство, калека.
Слово врач- не от враля и врать, а от способа лечения, приема, кровь - отворачивать, отворять и рукав заворачивать. Врачевать. Это одно из действенных приемов мобилизовать все силы организма, заставить его усиленно обновлять потерю крови при кровопускании. А слово лечить от латинизации и возврата в виде искажения.
Кустики из слов,  Растут. Калека. Лекало, подоплека—не просто подкладка, а подклад, делающий плечо кривым. И не видно.

А есть такое составное слово- вага. Палка такая помогает по болoту ходить, a еще и как рычаг. Га - означает путь, направление, ва- скорее всего видоизменение некоторого корня связанного с нынешним водить, искать, направлять. А замены Ж - Г свойственны в русском скорее всего благодаря путанице в произношении и написании латинских и русских начертаний одного звука.  Ж предпочтительней. Поэтому отважить означает отходить этой самой палкой по самое не балуйся. Рычаг от крика при применении данной палки и буквочку а сглотнули  а было рычажа, скорее всего. Тогда отважный важный - человек с таким оружием или посохом, короче с той самой важей- вагой

Дальше  от одного корня одно коренные слова типа. Вагон. Вожак. Отвага.Частью вернувшиеся в русский сохранив значение из других более поздних языков, наречий. По-видимому, и воз, возить и  возжи  с одним происхождением от этой палки.
Розга-  палка, уму разуму учить—направить.

Comment: Лекция Андрея Зализняка "О любительской лингвистике"
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ImRHeEe6j8

Answer (score -3):

ТАЙ-ГА
га - путь
тай - конец, завершение
отсюда и тайга - предел (конец) пути, конец дорогам
ист. http://obraz-slova.ru/index.php/slovar/?tr=tajjga

Comment: старославянское это слово

Comment: мистики  не надо. Слово тайна, уже достаточно объясняет. А происхождение этого слова яснее ясного,  Дай  и в ответ фига--на! То есть тайга-в конечном итоге--мать кормилица, и из тайги то все и несут. А с тайной это просто родственники по одному корню. Для кого мать родная, а для кого тайная дорога. Да и не дорога, а направление движения сразу становится тайной.
И вообще,  ни одной дороги в лесу не заканчивается.  Дороги соединяют, а не ведут в никуда.